# Output PHP Form Validation Error Messages When Using JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: javascript, php, validation, fetch-api

I have a page with multiple forms on, where each form is processed with PHP in the backend that sends data to a MySQL database, but on the front end it uses Javascript's fetchAPI to prevent the page refreshing when an instance of the form is completed and data is sent to the database.

I have some PHP server side validations that take place that still work in terms of not sending the data to the database, although on submission the instance of the form completed does disappear from the page (due to javascript shown below), but re-appears when refreshed if it failed the validations.

The main code example below includes this code block that would normally output the error message:

```
<?php 
    // echo form validation error messages
    if(isset($error)) {
        foreach($error as $msg) {
            echo "<p>** {$msg}</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

In terms of outputting these error messages is it possible to still use this PHP code (currently not working), or now I'm using the javascript fetchAPI in conjunction with PHP, will I have to also write validations in JavaScript to output the errors on the front end, in addition to the PHP ones which securely prevent the form failing the validations? It should be noted there are multiple instances of the form on the page which are outputted with a while loop, each one is in relation to a specific post.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload-submit'])) {
    // note $imageTitle is a variable given to the title of a post submitted via an HTML form

    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/', $imageTitle)) {
        $error[] = "Post Title can be letters and numbers only";
    }

    if(empty(trim($imageTitle))){
        $error[] = "Image Title cannot be blank";
    }

    // if no errors process submission
    if (!isset($error)) {

        try {

        // PDO prepared statements that update the database
    
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "There is an error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Also here is the javascript fetchAPI code that works on the page.

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.image-upload-details-form'),

forms.forEach(item => {
    
        item.querySelectorAll('[type="submit"], button').forEach(button => {
            button.addEventListener("click", e => item._button = button); //store this button in the form element
        })

        item.addEventListener("submit", function(evt, btn) {

            evt.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(this);
            if (this._button) //submitted by a button?
            {
            formData.set(this._button.name, this._button.value);
        }

        fetch("upload-details.php", {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        }).then(function(response){
            return response.text();
        }).then(function(text){
            console.log(text);
        }).catch(function (error){
            console.error(error);
        })

        // removes form when submitted
        item.remove();

    })

})
```

Many thanks in advance for any help / advice.

Comment: The PHP will still validate your information; however, the user will not see the error message unless you show it to the user. Something like `fetch(...).then(function(response) { alert(response); });` will display the error (if any) to the user. Whatever you `echo` in the PHP will go into the response text.

Comment: @code - I don't understand. How do I link the PHP to the error? Or do I need to write javascript error message in the `then` function, and how will it know it is an error? Apologies, but I am new to all of this.

Comment: are you getting anything from the logs?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is after making the fetch request you want to show the error message.

Your php code is incomplete. On pdo execption, you are outputting a string. On your validation, you are storing in an array.

Not clear about the output, if the validation fails.

(Recommended is output a string with html tags, so you can overcome the complexity of running a loop and creating dom nodes at js end)

While communicating with backend, best way is to use JSON format, to identify whether the response success or error

```
<?php 
    // echo form validation error messages // from php
    if(isset($error)) {
        foreach($error as $msg) {
            echo "<p>** {$msg}</p>";
        }
    }
    <div class="error-messages"></div> // for fetch error messages. leave it blank
?>


const errorElement = document.querySelector(".error-messages"); // capture error element
    errorElement.innerHTML =''; // clean previous errors

fetch("upload-details.php", {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
}).then(function(response){

    const echoed = response.text(); // assuming you are captuing the text
    if(echoed.includes("There is an error: ")){ // it is an error
        errorElement.innerHTML = echoed; // insert the error message into the div
        return;
    }
    return response.text();
    
}).then(function(text){
    console.log(text);
}).catch(function (error){
    errorElement.innerHTML = "Error communicating with server.Contact administrator"
    console.error(error);
})
```

Comment: Hi @Aleksandar I don't think this will work because the `"There is an error: "` catch block in my question is in relation to the actual submitted data after it passes the user input validations. That code block only runs if there are no errors in the validations because it is wrapped in the `if ( ! isset($error)) { // pdo PHP code }` i.e. if there are no user input errors ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have not give full php function code post method.

you have to write proper code in php which will give proper response of ajax call  like below

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
  // do user authentication as per your requirements
  // ...
  // ...
  // based on successful authentication
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 1));
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('success' => 0));
 }
```

after that you have to add code in javascript for handle error and success based on your php reponse.

```
function(response)
{
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);

    // user is logged in successfully in the back-end
    // let's redirect
    if (jsonData.success == "1")
    {
        location.href = 'my_profile.php';
    }
    else
    {
        alert('Invalid Credentials!');
    }
}
```

This is proper way for ajax call request. Use proper code for that and your problem will solve

Comment: Yes the PHP is actually part of a post request, but I simplified the code in the question because it wasn't getting any answers (there was a lot of code initially).  I don't see how that is going to show the specific errors related the validations though?

Comment: Also I've updated the question and put the `if(isset($_POST['upload-submit'])) { // PHP}` if statement back in. I took this and the prepared statements etc out because it was so much code it was a bit overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo you error(s) all in one time, otherwise you'll get the 1st echo only... ;

```
<?php 
        // echo form validation error messages
        $echo = [];
        if(isset($error)) {
            foreach($error as $msg) {
                $echo[] = "<p>** {$msg}</p>";
            }
        echo implode(PHP_EOL, $echo);
        }
    ?>
```

And for you other block :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['upload-submit'])) {
    // note $imageTitle is a variable given to the title of a post submitted via an HTML form

    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/', $imageTitle)) {
        $error[] = "Post Title can be letters and numbers only";
    }

    if(empty(trim($imageTitle))){
        $error[] = "Image Title cannot be blank";
    }

    // if no errors process submission
    if (!isset($error)) {

        try {
        $success = false;
        // PDO prepared statements that update the database => success = true ?
        echo $success;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "There is an error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
    echo $errors; // form 'user' errors
}
?>
```

or smthg like that

Answer (score -3):

1. When you catch PDOException you *make echo* (but not *throw new Exeption*).
   So in JS it goes to *then(function(response)*, not to catch(function (error).
2. You should **check response in then(function(response)**.
   Example:

   ```
    .then(function(response){
      if (response.includes('Error:') {
        // do something
      }
   ```

Comment: This makes little sense in relation to the question. You should give a proper code example and explantion in relation to the code shown.