# Show PHP Validation Errors When Using JavaScript Fetch()

Tags: javascript, php, error-handling, promise, fetch

I would like to output an error message that works on the backend with PHP whilst using the JavaScript fetchAPI on the frontend. There is a very similar question here: [Output PHP Form Validation Error Messages When Using JavaScript Fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69322979/output-php-form-validation-error-messages-when-using-javascript-fetch-api) but I think because of the volume of code in that question the problem looks more daunting than perhaps it is. By the look of it this person is doing the same tutorial I'm doing.

In my case (prior to using the JS `fetch()`), if there were errors in the PHP validations an error message was echoed to the screen with the following code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($error)) {
        foreach($error as $errorMessage) {
            echo "<p>You have an error: {$errorMessage}</p>";
        }
    }
?>
```

A simpflied version of the form processing would be:

```
<?php

    // note $postTitle is a variable given to the title of a post submitted via an HTML form

    if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$/', $postTitle)) {
        $error[] = "Post Title can be letters and numbers only";
    }

    // if no errors process submission
    if (!isset($error)) {

        try {

        // PDO prepared statements that update the database with article/post information
    
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "There is an error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

    }

?>
```

The Javascript is:

```
var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form'),

forms.forEach(item => {

        item.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            const formData = new FormData(this);

            fetch("news-posts.php", {
                method: 'post',
                body: formData
            }).then(function(response){
                return response.text();
            }).then(function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }).catch(function (error){
                console.error(error);
            })

            item.remove();

    })

})
```

The problem is that although the error handling still works as expected in the backend, how do you output the error message in the frontend, now it uses the JS Fetch() method?

Comment: PHP error handling (and most server side languages that aren’t bound to a framework) is generally expected to be in a 1990’s HTTP browser context. When a non-browser is involved, be it AJAX, fetch or an API, you should respond to all requests in a non-browser fashion. These days that means JSON but it could anything. So, server-side, return a standard response, and if there is an error, return a similar response, but one that can be identified as an error.

Comment: Another way to say that is to catch all errors and return them consistently. You can do this manually, through a framework, through a base class or trait, or through a central router.

Comment: I would not give `e->getMessage()` results to users. Log that and give a general message, `Database failed to execute` or something.

Comment: @user3783243, I don’t disagree, however I would just say that every error needs to be handled with context. This comes back to the common “username or password is incorrect” message, which shows how information can leak through a side channel.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - I do understand that bit (your first point). I just don't know how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't a universal way to do this and it really depends on how closely your client and server-side code are to each other. If your server-side code only "knows" your client-side to a limited degree, the former can just return an error code with the literal message such as "The title must contain XYZ", and the latter can have a central location for all error messages. Another option is for the server to return error messages tied to each field id and the client then puts those error messages next to each field.

Answer (score 1):

You need a way for the JS to know when it receives an error. Ideally your backend would return an http status code related to the error and you can check for this in the frontend.

Backend:

```php
if (isset($error)) {
    header('400 Bad Request');
    // output errors here
}
```

Frontend:

```js
fetch("news-posts.php", {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData
}).then(function(response) {
  if (!response.ok) {
    // handle errors here
  }
});
```

Also, you may want to output the errors in json format and loop through them in the JS. You don't need to output tags like `<p>` for every error, just the data. Those tags can be added by the JS itself, dynamically.

The following example loops through a `data` object, creates a `<p>` element for each item and appends them to the div with id `error`:

```js
let errorElement = document.querySelector('#error');
for (let error of data.errors) {
  let listItem = document.createElement('p');
  listItem.textContent = error.message;
  errorElement.appendChild(listItem);
}
```

You should be able to modify those examples to fit your need.

Comment: thanks. In the `// handle errors here` I don't understand how I'd do that with JSON, and how do I link that to a particular validation failure if I have more than one validation test (which in reality I do)? i.e. If in the example code if the validation that fails is the Post Title not being letters and numbers only, how do I show it's that particular validation that failed?

Comment: @pjk_ok I just added another example on how to display the data receiving a json object. If it's too complicated for you, you can output a plain text and have the JS append it in an element using `element.innerHTML = error;`